# How to interpret Crockford's JavaScript Trim function?

Tags: javascript, methods

I'm going through the JavaScript Programming Language series by Douglas Crockford and came across this expression in his trim function:

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
  return this.replace(/^\s*(\S*(\s+\S+)*)\s*$/, "$1");
};
```

I get what it does but how in the world does it work?

Comment: The regular expression isolates anything in the string that's between leading and trailing whitespace.  I don't think that the complexity of the central part is necessary, but there might be some subtlety I'm missing. *edit* (it may be a performance thing to reduce backtracking etc.)

Comment: @Pointy today is the first time I'm hearing the term regular expression. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should grab a tool like [expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm), where you can step through the regex...

`^\s*` - Whitespace at the beginning of the line or string, with any number of repetitions

`(\S*(\s+\S+)*)` - Capture group, number "$1" in your example.

`\S*(\s+\S+)*` - Anything but whitespace, any number of repetions

`(\s+\S+)*` - Another capture group, which looks for whitespace with one or more repetitions and anything other than whitespace with one or more repetitions.

`\s*$` - Any number of whitespaces at the end of the line or string.

What it looks like in Expresso...

[image: Expresso Screenshot]